# Matlab:How to eleiminate the black background and retain the region of interest in my image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold

I have the following IR (infrared) image of a human fist captured with a webcamera converted to work in IR. The picture has captured the veins under the skin. What i want to do is just retain the fist and get rid of the surrounding black area. How do i do this in MATLAB?

[image]

Here is what I have done so far, but I'm just getting a black image for this

```
a=imread('1.jpg'); 
figure; imshow(a); 
b=rgb2gray(a); 
figure; 
imshow(b); 
[j,k]=size(b); 
for g=1:j 
for f=1:k 
if b(j,k)>0.06 
c(j,k)=0; 
else c(j,k)=1; 
end 
end
 end 
figure,imshow(c);
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing incorrectly, and how I can accomplish what I want? Also when i mean i want to get rid of the background i mean I want a white background instead of the black one>Cos the purpose of this project is to retain just the veins, the veins will be retained as black . and then i will take the co ordinates of these points .So i dont want the background to be generated as co ordinates as well...! So i want the background as white ..! how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29) and is a big topic in image processing. Your image is quite nice, so if you have the image processing toolbox this is pretty easy. And even if you don't its still not that hard.

As Chris mentions, you should convert your image to double before doing anything with it. If you have the image processing toolbox you can then use the function [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/graythresh.html) to find the best threshold level. Please note that you don't need to use for loops to do thresholding, in MATLAB you can threshold the entire matrix in one line.

```
b = im2double(b);              %convert to double
thresh_level = graythresh(b);  %find best threshold level
c = b > thresh_level;          %do thresholding
imshow(c)
```

[image: segmented image]

This gives you a binary image, where your fist has value 1 and the background label 0. To keep the fist as it was, we multiply the binary version with the original version. Now the background is all zero, and the fist keeps its original values.

```
d = im2double(c).*b;           %c is binary, so we need to convert it first
imshow(d,[])
```

[image: fist]

If you don't have the image processing toolbox you need to choose the threshold level manually. This can be a bit tricky. You used 0.06, but graythresh suggests that 0.2980 is the best. I find that a good way to find the threshold value is to look at the histogram of the image.

```
hist(b(:),256);
```

[image: histogram]

We can clearly see from the histogram that we have two clusters of points and that the any value between 2 and 3 would separate the clusters fairly well. So we should use a value in that interval to do thresholding.

Comment: @khadeejah: i think this answers your question, and you should accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of problems I see:

In your code you use g and f as loop counters, but you always access the b array as b(j,k).

As well, the imread reads a uint8, so you can't really compare that to a double (0.06). So convert to a double via:

```
b=im2double(b);
```

Also, not a big deal in this case, but you dynamically grow c each loop iteration. If the image is large, this will dramatically hinder the performanec of your code. Per allocate it via:

```
c=ones(j,k);
```

After these changes it produces something resembling your fist. However, because the background is not a uniform colour, it doesn't work overly well. This part is outside my realm of experience...

Comment: bt i want the palm to stay as it is . here in hwatever you ve said its turned black ..:( So what to do now ..:(

Comment: That is what your code does. Use Gjaul's answer, it's better. I have no image analysis experience so all I could do was fix your code so it would "work".

Comment: he he @chris ..thanks so much ! :D yea ghauls really did the thing ..! :D